# Javascript cookies not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to use a cookie to save the color chosen by the user to set the body of my site's pages. Now the cookie is being set fine but for some reason I seem to get it working. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks.

Console Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
var bgColour = getCookie('bgColour');

if (bgColour == "01") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor01";
}
if (bgColour == "02") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor02";
}
if (bgColour == "03") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor03";
}
if (bgColour == "04") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor04";
}
if (bgColour == "05") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor05";
}

function color1() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=01";
}

function color2() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=02";
}

function color3() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=03";
}

function color4() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=04";
}

function color5() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=05";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.bgColor00 {
  background-color: #f6f4fb;
}

.bgColor01 {
  background-color: #80b3ff;
}

.bgColor02 {
  background-color: #afe9af;
}

.bgColor03 {
  background-color: #ffb380;
}

.bgColor04 {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
}

.bgColor05 {
  background-color: #eeaaff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body id="body">
  <button onClick="color1()">Blue</button>
  <button onClick="color2()">Green</button>
  <button onClick="color3()">Orange</button>
  <button onClick="color4()">Red</button>
  <button onClick="color5()">Purple</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: aside from the stack sandbox error, what error are you getting?

Comment: I'll update the post with the error now

Comment: I'm not really familiar with cookies in JavaScript, but I see you interchange `color` and `colour` a few times. I would be more consistent, this _might_ actually solve your problem as well.

Comment: Did you tried something more? Did my code helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you place the script outside the `<html>` tag. I tried doing like this:

```
<html>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.bgColor00 {
  background-color: #f6f4fb;
}

.bgColor01 {
  background-color: #80b3ff;
}

.bgColor02 {
  background-color: #afe9af;
}

.bgColor03 {
  background-color: #ffb380;
}

.bgColor04 {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
}

.bgColor05 {
  background-color: #eeaaff;
}
</style>
<body id="body">
  <button onClick="color1()">Blue</button>
  <button onClick="color2()">Green</button>
  <button onClick="color3()">Orange</button>
  <button onClick="color4()">Red</button>
  <button onClick="color5()">Purple</button>
</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
var bgColour = getCookie('bgColour');

if (bgColour == "01") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor01";
}
if (bgColour == "02") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor02";
}
if (bgColour == "03") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor03";
}
if (bgColour == "04") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor04";
}
if (bgColour == "05") {
  document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor05";
}

function color1() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=01";
}

function color2() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=02";
}

function color3() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=03";
}

function color4() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=04";
}

function color5() {
  document.cookie = "bgColour=05";
}
</script>
</html>
```

And it works (no error occurs), the only issue is that is not dynamic the change, you have to refresh the page. Maybe a location.reload will work for you, or you will need to call the :

```
document.getElementById("body").className = "bgColor0X";
```

inside each `colorX()` function. Then, the color will change at the click moment, not only on reload.

I made this working example: https://codepen.io/jpaulet/pen/LLVjGO
Hope it helps!